# Continuous map and convexity

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two vector spaces. Let $f:X\longrightarrow Y$ be a continuous map.

> If $C$ is a convex set of $Y$. Is $f^{-1}(C)$ a convex set of $X$? If not I hope to get a counterexample.

Thank you

Comment: The term “convex set” has no meaning in a topological space.

Comment: thank you. So I should replace topological by vector space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Take $\sin\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ and $C=\{0\}$.

Comment: I think also that if $C$ is a connected set of $Y$, then $f^{-1}(C)$ is not necessary a connected set of $X$. Do you agree with me? Thank you

Comment: Yes, same counterexample!